# Как вывести картинки из БД если есть связи между таблицами

Tags: mysql

Есть БД, в ней 3 таблицы (table1, table2, table3).

Table1 and table2 склеены при помощи join.

Table1 имеют столбцы(id, name),

Table2 (id, name),

Table3 (id, url).

Table1 имеет связь с table2 как один ко многим.

Table2 имеет связь с table3 один к одному.

В html есть чекбоксы,при выборе которых берется name из table1.

Так вот,как сделать запрос в БД на PDO, чтобы при выборе одного или нескольких чекбоксов(name из table1) выводились соответствующие картинки из table3?

Comment: но....вы же....уже знаете о join....

Comment: Нет,таблицу мне дали как задание! Помогите,кто разбирается в этом.